# Is this an acceptable way of creatin a login for a single user?

Tags: php, security

I want to create a page on my website which is only avaluable to administrators. This page is to allow them to edit or delete entries in a MySQL database. No username should be needed to access this page. Would the method shown in the following (php) code be acceptable, or are there better/safer ways of doing this?

```
if (password = 'MyPassword') {
  echo "**The code needed to display the admin page**";
}
else {
  echo "access denied"
}
```

Where this code would be embedded within a login page as follows:

```
<html>
<form method='post'>
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<? include('abovecode.php') ?>

</html>
```

Comment: You have to decide what level of security you need for your application. I assume the code above is pseudo-code as it has a few errors. It is so simple to use the new password api in PHP though that I see no reason not to at the very least store a hash of the admin password and using password_verify to check the supplied password against it.

Comment: you need `==` comparison operator `if (password == 'MyPassword')` instead of `=` assignment operator `if (password = 'MyPassword')`

Comment: also, `<?` is special syntax that's not available without modifications to default php.ini. use `<?php` for better portability to use on other servers.

Comment: missing semicolon `;` will throw error here `echo "access denied"`

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to make modifications on that one page, then what you are showing will work, though there are problems as JimL stated (such as password = 'MyPassword').

That said, you should hash the password before posting, because that could be read, and you should test it in the target page.

All that said, if the "admin" section needs to have multiple pages, you should use a PHP session to save whether the admin is validated or not.